# How do I prohibit a specific function call with Rubocop?

Tags: ruby, rubocop

I have a Rails project where we're migrating towards using an image proxy to serve our ActiveStorage images. As part of this migration, we need to change all existing usages of `url_for()` to `ix_image_url()`.

`url_for` will continue to exist, but in order to prevent other developers from accidentally using the wrong function in the future and accidentally serving an unproxied image, I'd like to "ban" use of `url_for` within our project.

Is this possible?

Comment: You can add a custom cop [This Article](https://mwallba.io/custom-rubocops-to-support-code-reviews/) does a great job of describing implementation.

Comment: If this is Rails, you can use [`deprecate`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Module.html#method-i-deprecate) instead.

Answer (score 0):

### Just Grep for the Method Call

While you could certainly [write your own cop](https://docs.rubocop.org/rubocop/development.html), the use case you're defining seems like it would be a better fit for a simple grep done on your continuous integration server. For example:

```sh
if egrep -Rn '\burl_for' '/path/to/source/tree'; then
  echo 'error: use ix_image_url instead of url_for' >&2
  exit 1
fi
```

can be run as a build or test step in your CI pipeline. It will print the offending lines, along with filenames and line numbers, and send your "how to fix it" custom message to standard error for reporting the build failure.

Note that shell commands like this can be run in most CI implementations, but you can certainly embody it in a cop or inline it into your pipeline (e.g. Groovy code for Jenkins jobs) if that works better for you. However, the KISS principle argues for keeping the implementation as simple as possible, so I'd avoid the necessity of mucking around with ASTs or the maintenance overhead of custom cops unless you are getting a lot more bang for your buck than the use case described in your original question.